# How to search for related words with python

Tags: python, nlp

I need to write a search program that returns not just matched words but also related words.

For example, I have a list like below:

```
['pet', 'apple', 'dog', 'cat', 'desk', 'orange']
```

I need to write a python program that when I search for 'pet', it also returns 'cat', 'dog'.
Is that possible to do in python using NLP? Thanks.

Comment: why `pet` will return `cat` or `dog` unless you define some sort of relationship between them?

Comment: It is possible. Dataset-> program-> train-> result

Comment: create a dictionary maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure but I think you want to  create an entity of pet 
but if you don't want to solve it using NLP you can use Dictionary

I am not sure that I understand your question but I tried to answer it

Comment: if I am correct and you want to approach either of solution I will re-edit according to that